# $stateChangeStart - State-change not prevented

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

If a user without authorization tries to access a restricted state, the restricted state loades before he is sent back by `$state.go(fromState.name)`. It seems like the `event.preventDefault();` doesn't fire?

```
$rootScope.$on('$stateChangeStart', 
               function (event, toState, toParams, fromState, fromParams) {

    if (toState.name == 'app.admin' || toState.name == 'app.bonus') {
        AuthService.isAuthenticated().then(function (response) {
            if (!response) {
                event.preventDefault();
                $rootScope.$broadcast(AUTH_EVENTS.notAuthenticated);
            } else {
                event.preventDefault();
                if ('data' in toState && 'authorizedRoles' in toState.data) {
                    var authorizedRoles = toState.data.authorizedRoles;
                    if (!AuthService.isAuthorized(authorizedRoles)) {
                        $state.go(fromState.name, {}, {
                            reload: true
                        });
                        $rootScope.$broadcast(AUTH_EVENTS.notAuthorized);
                    }
                }
            }
        }, function () {
            event.preventDefault();
            $rootScope.$broadcast(AUTH_EVENTS.notAuthenticated);
        });
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're calling `event.preventDefault()` from an asynchronous callback. So, at the time it's called, the event listener function has already returned, and since the event hasn't been prevented, the router has navigated to the next state.

It would work if you did

```
$rootScope.$on('$stateChangeStart', function(event, toState, toParams, fromState, fromParams) {
    if ((toState.name == 'app.admin' || toState.name == 'app.bonus')
        && !AuthService.isAuthenticated()) {
        event.preventDefault();
    }
}
```

But of course, that means your service needs to return a boolean synchronously, rather than a promise.